# Make a chrome extension that replaces divs on certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My wife plays neopets and is constantly editing her profile page's html.  I would like to make an extension for chrome that just replaces a textarea with an advanced text editor.  I would like any links in the right direction. This will be a learning project for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify: your question title and content seem to suggest different things.  Do you want to replace some content in `<div>`s or enhance a textarea with a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Google is your friend. Try searching for CKEditor.

Comment: I have seen the editor i want to use.  All I was looking for is some links showing a way to make a chrome extension that can replace elements on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), which will automatically inject some code when the page is loaded.